# jquery append to html with image then remove it not being displayed

Tags: jquery, append

Hey all i am trying to get my jquery code below to work:

```
function submitContactUs() {
    if ($('#cf-name-txt').val() == '' || $('#cf-name-txt').val().charAt(0) == '*') {
        $('#cf-name-txt').append("<img src=\"img/attention.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" style=\"position:absolute; left: -7px; top: 7px;\" />");
    }       
}
```

And the HTML code is this:

```
<div id="contactus-name">
    <input type="text" id="cf-name-txt" style="width: 200px;" class="formBoxesContact" value="*Your Name">
</div>
```

It works with adding the image to the end of the html code above but its not displaying? It looks like this in firebug:

[image: firebug]

What am i doing to cause it not to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#cf-name-txt').after("<img src=\"img/attention.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" style=\"position:absolute; left: -7px; top: 7px;\" />");
```

OR

```
$("<img src=\"img/attention.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" style=\"position:absolute; left: -7px; top: 7px;\" />").insertAfter($('#cf-name-txt'));
```

You are trying to append image to input.. Try appending after the input tag..

`.after()` should work

**EDIT**

```
if( !$('#cf-name-txt').next('img').length)
$('#cf-name-txt').after("<img src=\"img/attention.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" style=\"position:absolute; left: -7px; top: 7px;\" />");​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xp5sE/)

Comment: Awesome... it keeps generating an image every time i push the button to submit... how do i stop that?

Comment: Add a if condition to check for the Image and only then add it.. check Edit

Comment: Try this statement  ..if (!$('#cf-name-txt').next('img').length) {

Comment: awesome Sushanth! That got it!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying do display an image inside an input. try using an styled editable div or something.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to insert the image *after* the input, not inside of it.
For that, use jQuery's `after` function, instead of `append`.

As an alternative, you can use a CSS class to add the image beside the input, and spare the embedded HTML inside your javascript.

On your CSS:

```css
input.attention:after {
  content: url('img/attention.png');
}
```

Then, on the javascript:

```js
function submitContactUs() {
  if ($('#cf-name-txt').val() == '' || $('#cf-name-txt').val().charAt(0) == '*') {
      $('#cf-name-txt').addClass("attention");
    }       
}
```

Comment: In that case there's no `img` element, the image is displayed on the input's [`::after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::after)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like (from the name of your image) that you are basically wanting to show an "attention" image when a form has been submitted and a field has not been entered.

As the other posts say, you cannot put an image inside the `<input>` tag, however this does not mean that you can not have an image appear inside the tag.

The way to do this is to set the `background` style of the `input`. So to do this with jQuery, use;

```
$('#cf-name-txt').addClass('alert-icon');
```

Then have the css

```
input.alert-icon{ background: url(img/attention.png) no-repeat right center; }
```

You can then play about with the styling, also remove the class when a user set the focus onto the input.

Answer (score 1):

A input field cannot contain a  element (As well as pretty much anything).
Use $('#cf-name-txt').before(""); to add the image and 
$("#cf-name-txt-img").remove() to delete it.

Or even better, Put the image in the HTML with style display:none and turn it on changing the style in display:block

```
   <div id="contactus-name">
    <img src="img/attention.png" id="cf-name-txt-img" width="16" height="16" style="position:absolute; left: -7px; top: 7px; display:none" />
    <input type="text" id="cf-name-txt" style="width: 200px;" class="formBoxesContact" value="*Your Name">
   </div>
```

And use $("#cf-name-txt-img").show() to display it, $("#cf-name-txt-img").hide() to remove it.

In your case:

```
function submitContactUs() {
    var $img = $("#cf-name-txt-img");
    if ($('#cf-name-txt').val() == '' || $('#cf-name-txt').val().charAt(0) == '*') {
       $img.show();
    } else {
       $img.hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll have more than one input box that will need the icon. I am just wanting to append it to whatever box needs it when they try submitting the form and they leave something out. Really do not want to manually put the img next to each input tag...